# How to redirect to a mobile app in Azure B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'd like to be able to set up a redirect URI to a mobile app while working with Azure B2C, to have a link like:

```
https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_OTP_SIGNIN_TEST&client_id=xxxxx-35b9-4f9f-8ae8-fde40abfe4c8&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=myapp%3A%2F%2Fauth&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login'
```

Notice the parameter

```
redirect_uri=myapp%3A%2F%2Fauth
```

However, Azure B2C seems to accept only HTTPS. How can I achieve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you register the application with Azure B2C, you can mention "Reply Url" aka Redirect URI for each of the platforms( web, desktop, native client,etc). Provide the redirect URI with `scheme://<path>` in order to redirect your user to a native **mobile app**, refer this documentation [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-native-application?tabs=app-reg-ga) for more details. This [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android) has details on how the native app must have the `scheme` and handle path in it's configuration so that it uses the B2C provided token and claims.